# How to change the font, axis and tick color in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, color

How do I change the label, axis and tick color of this plot:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

% package for plots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax=11100,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=5200,
        domain=0:1000,
        xlabel=Generation,
        ylabel=Fitness,
        axis line style=->,
        axis x line*=none,
        axis y line*=none,
        scaled x ticks=false,
        scaled y ticks=false,
        xtick={0,2000,...,11000},
        ytick={0,1000,...,5000},
        tick align=outside,
        every axis plot/.append style={
            line join=round,
            line cap=round,
            clip=false,    
            thick
        },
        tick align=outside,
        x tick label style={
            rotate=45,
            anchor=north east
        },
        axis on top,
        legend style={
            anchor=south,
            at={(0.5,1.1)},
            legend columns=2,
            draw=none,
            fill=none
        },
        cycle list/Dark2
        ]
        \addplot{rnd};
        \addlegendentryexpanded{Legend 1}
        \addplot{rnd};
        \addlegendentryexpanded{Legend 2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I may, a minor point about your example: currently it relies on data files we don't have access to. But seeing as your question doesn't really involve the data at all, you could just replace the plots with e.g. `\addplot{rnd};`

Comment: I changed it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the axis lines (I assume that's what you meant), add the colour of your choice (and any other options) to the `axis line style` you already have there. I.e.

```
axis line style={->, green, very thick}
```

For the other three `<foo> style={<colourname>}`, where `<foo>` is `xlabel`, `ylabel` or `tick`. E.g.

```
    xlabel style={blue},
    ylabel style={red},
    tick style={cyan, ultra thick}
```

Those colours look rather ghastly of course, but I'll leave the colour choice to you. :)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

% package for plots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax=11100,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=5200,
        domain=0:1000,
        xlabel=Generation,
        ylabel=Fitness,
        axis line style={->, green, very thick},
        axis x line*=none,
        axis y line*=none,
        scaled x ticks=false,
        scaled y ticks=false,
        xtick={0,2000,...,11000},
        ytick={0,1000,...,5000},
        tick align=outside,
        every axis plot/.append style={
            line join=round,
            line cap=round,
            clip=false,    
            thick
        },
        tick align=outside,
        x tick label style={
            rotate=45,
            anchor=north east
        },
        axis on top,
        legend style={
            anchor=south,
            at={(0.5,1.1)},
            legend columns=2,
            draw=none,
            fill=none
        },
        cycle list/Dark2,
        xlabel style={blue},
        ylabel style={red},
        tick style={cyan, ultra thick}
        ]
 \addplot{rnd};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the tick labels, which I forgot, you already have an `x tick label style` where you can set the colour for those. Naturally there's a `y tick label style` as well which you can add, or use `tick label style={yellow}` to set all tick labels to a suitable colour.

Comment: Thanks! That is awesome. However, how do I change the legend colors as well?

Comment: @weisbrja Would it surprise you if I said "add `<colour>` to the `legend style`"? E.g. if you add `blue` to the `legend style`, all the text becomes blue. If you want to different colours, use the optional argument to `\addlegendentry`, e.g. `\addlegendentry[red]{foo} \addlegendentry[magenta]{bar}`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It all works!